# Swagger codegen discriminated values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, swagger, swagger-codegen

We are using Swagger 2.0 to define our API. We have a model like this in the swagger.yaml:

```
Reading:
  title: Reading
  type: object
  discriminator: type
  properties:
    type: 
      $ref: '#/definitions/ReadingType'

SensorReading:
  description: Teralytic probe reading
  allOf:
    - $ref: "#/definitions/Reading"
    - properties:
        value:
          description: Sensor reading value
          type: number
          format: float64
```

We use swagger-codegen 2.4.0 to generate the python client and are using python 3.7.0.

The issue we are having is when we call our client:

```
response = api_instance.readings_query(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)

for result in api_response:
        for reading in result.readings:
            if reading.type == 'SensorReading':
                reading.__class__ = SensorReading
                pprint(reading)
```

This is how we assumed we would "cast" our reading back to its specific type but this doesn't seem to work.

We get an error back similar to:

```
AttributeError: 'SensorReading' object has no attribute '_value'
```

It seems that swagger-codegen for python doesn't quite support this, unless we are totally missing something.